# Rendering of the double surface integral, Tex

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

It has recently come to my attention that the double surface intregral, namely \oiint, does not work for this site. How can we fix this?

Example: [How to infer what integrals and derivatives signify and when to take them?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286268/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6779/2451